# The best way to implement subquery with multiple columns selection in Hibernate?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate

I want to implement subquery with multiple columns for grouping purposes with Criteria API. I as know it's not possible with Criteria API and also I cannot use native query.

There is an example of database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS conversation (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS participant (
    id              BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    conversation_id BIGINT REFERENCES conversation (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message (
    id              BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at      TIMESTAMP,
    conversation_id BIGINT REFERENCES conversation (id),
    sender_id       BIGINT REFERENCES participant (id),
    receiver_id     BIGINT REFERENCES participant (id)
);

INSERT INTO conversation (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO participant (conversation_id) VALUES (1), (1), (1), (2), (2), (3), (3), (3), (3);
INSERT INTO message (conversation_id, sender_id, receiver_id) VALUES (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 5), (2, 5, 4), (2, 5, 4), (3, 9, 6), (3, 9, 7), (3, 9, 8);
```

I want to get last messages from each conversation. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM message m
WHERE (m.conversation_id, m.created_at)
  IN (SELECT
        m.conversation_id,
        max(m.created_at)
      FROM message m
      GROUP BY m.conversation_id);
```

The first way I found is to concat two columns. It's not very robust:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM message m
WHERE concat(m.conversation_id, m.created_at)
  IN (SELECT concat(m.conversation_id,
                    max(m.created_at))
      FROM message m
      GROUP BY m.conversation_id);
```

The second way is to use [aggregate functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45609) to find the identifier of max value for each group. It slows performance and there are problems with ordering inside the aggregate function for Criteria API.

Is there any way to replace subquery with something reliable and fast without using native query/HQL/JPQL?

Comment: Can you use `ROW_NUMBER` in Hibernate?

Comment: @lad2025 As I know, Criteria API doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER` function.