# Get last row grouping by column on LINQ C# using PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, linq

I want to get the last row for each **id_category** based on **date_event**. I have a SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM log t1
JOIN 
(
   SELECT id_category, MAX(date_event) AS MAXDATE
   FROM log
   GROUP BY id_category
) t2
ON t1.id_category = t2.id_category
AND t1.date_event = t2.MAXDATE
```

And I want to "translate" it to LINQ (using Entity Framework 6). Here is what I tried so far:

```
db.log
  .GroupBy(m => m.id_category)
  .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(m => m.date_event).FirstOrDefault());
```

But, PostgreSQL returns:

> PostgresException: 42601: syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Funny thing is that it is common pattern today: latest per group + ORM + PostgreSQL [The best way to implement subquery with multiple columns selection in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571309/the-best-way-to-implement-subquery-with-multiple-columns-selection-in-hibernate).

Comment: So what does the generated SQL statement look like?